# What should I return in a member function if a condition is not met?

Tags: c++, exception, return

For example:

```
class Foo{
   int data;
   // ...
}
```

And there is a member function:

```
Foo func(int a){
  if(a > 10) return Foo(a);
  else {} // problem is here, I do not want return 
             any Foo object, do I throw exception? how?
}
```

So, I do not want to return a new empty `Foo` object in else block, how can I handle this situation in an idiomatic way?

Comment: throw an exception ? What's the problem ?

Comment: How are you calling this function? What does the caller expect if a is less than 10?

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Comment: in such cases I also consider returning a pointer to an new Foo object, and return nullptr if ever a > 10 is false. Though exception could reinforce the fact that you think this case should not be supported by your function.

Comment: Stephane is right, pointer works well, but I do want to return object, and caller expect nothing if a<=10

Comment: You shouldn't return a raw pointer. The user will have no clear idea if it should be deleted or not.

Comment: If you declare function to return an object, it has to return an object. In this case you can use Null Object Design Pattern.

Comment: Can you split it into 2 functions. One to be called when `a` (whatever that is) is >10, and another which doesn't return anything, otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pre-condition is absolutely needed for the function to continue, then throwing an exception is the proper way of handling it. If the condition isn't required explicitly throughout the rest of the function, then you have a couple options:

- Return a unique pointer that manages a pointer, i.e. `std::unique_ptr`. I don't recommend this approach because it has unnecessary dynamic memory allocation.
- Return `boost::optional<Foo>` or in a future TS `std::experimental::optional<Foo>`. This expresses intent that the value may or may not be there.
- Re-evaluate your design. Why does the return depend on the condition? What could be done differently? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you've found that there's some scenario in which your function should suddenly not be returning a value, then either:

- throw an exception, or
- your design is broken

Answer (score -2):

your best bet is to return a pointer:

```
Foo* func(int a){
  if(a > 10) return new Foo(a);
  else return 0; // else return plain zerro
}
```

C++11

```
Foo* func(int a){
  if(a > 10) return new Foo(a);
  else return nullptr;
}
```

of course you'll need to check if returned object does exist in your calling function:

```
Foo* ptr = func(5);
if(ptr)
{
    // use ptr
    *ptr;
}
else
{
    // do not use it
}

// and delete it
if(ptr) delete ptr;

// in c++11 version no need to check just:
delete ptr;
```

sorry I didn't see you do not want to return 0...

```
Foo* func(int a){
  if(a > 10) return new Foo(a);
  else throw(a);
}

try
{
    Foo* get = func(4); // this will throw
}

catch(int)
{
     //handle the error here
}
```

Comment: This is a blunt instrument. I don't think you've considered (or are aware of) the subtleties of design issues that this raises. Please read Rapptz's answer to find out.